# Indexing in MongoDB - Using Regex Match

Tags: regex, database, mongodb, indexing

Applying indexing on an attribute that's been used to match documents using regex.

I'm querying a collection with a regex match in the query. Consider following Spring Data Mongo query:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("user_id").regex(userId,"i"));
mongoTemplate.find(query,User.class);
```

Now, if I apply indexing on the same attribute, 'user_id', can it lead to slow performance than no indexing? If yes, then how do I apply indexing on such fields?

**EDIT:**

After testing some APIs having similar queries using JMeter, I found that normal indexing slowed down the performance. Then implemented [TextIndexDefinition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/TextIndexDefinition.html) with TextCriteria's matchingAny function. But it doesn't match substring with a string like regex do. Therefore, not of my use.

Comment: Use explain to show the plan - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/explain/.  It may not be using the index.  Remember a regex that results in an equivalent "CONTAINS" type of operation will not use an index.  For SQL syntax, a WHERE clause such as "LIKE %ABC%" is semantically a "CONTAINS" condition.  Likewise, a criteria asking for a wildcard at the begging of the filter predicate will not use an index.  Using SQL as an example - "LIKE %ABC".8

Comment: In your case, I believe the "i" is a parameter to regex to mean - do a case-insensitive search.  If this is the case, you must have a case-insensitive collation on the collection, then you must specify the collation in the query. -  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/collation/

Comment: @barrypicker, you are right. Text Index isn't being used. Can you please suggest what should I do now?